# Remove phone numbers from text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a text column in SQL Server, there are personal phone numbers which I want to replace with # for each numbers. Please see examples below:

```
'07555815825'
'CALL ME ON 07585815826'
'TEXT 07545815826 TEST'
'TEXT 07545815826 TEST its 2020'
```

I have tried cross apply and string split but cannot get the desired results.

Below are the desired results:

```
'###########'
'CALL ME ON ###########'
'TEXT ########### TEST'
'TEXT ########### TEST its 2020'
```

Comment: This will be very hard to handle using TSQL, which doesn't have regex support.  Handle it outside your database.

Comment: How are *you* defining a phone number? Clearly it's not just any sequences of digits, per your last example. You need to clearly describe how *you* can identify a phone number before you can expect a computer to be able to do that same.

Comment: the phone number is 11 sequential digits and can be in any part of the text as per my examples

Comment: I am looking to replace the any sequence of 11 consecutive digits in text with ###########

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: it is version 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data has exactly 11-digit phone numbers and only one phone number per text.  With these constraints, you can use `stuff()`:

```
select v.text,
       stuff(text, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', text + '00000000000'), 11, 'XXXXXXXXXXX')
from (values ('07555815825'),
             ('CALL ME ON 07585815826'),
             ('TEXT 07545815826 TEST'),
             ('TEXT 07545815826 TEST its 2020')
     ) v(text);
```

Note:  This also handles texts that have no phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it as you want using native tql syntax because you don't have a builtin regex feature, but you can use other builtin functions to create something similar to regex.
here is a function,**I found it in stackoverflow when I had the same need**, that you can add to your solution that can help you with your need

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ReplaceWithPattern
(
    @InputString VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Pattern VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ReplaceString VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ReplaceLength INT = 1
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index INT;

    set @Index = patindex(@Pattern, @InputString);

    while @Index > 0
    begin
        --replace matching character at index
        set @InputString = stuff(@InputString, patindex(@Pattern, @InputString), @ReplaceLength, @ReplaceString);
        set @Index = patindex(@Pattern, @InputString);
    end;
    
    return @InputString;
END;
```

To use it, you do so

```
declare @textString VARCHAR(250) = '07555815825
CALL ME ON 07585815826
TEXT 07545815826 TEST
TEXT 07545815826 TEST its 2020'
 --select Replace(@textString, Substring(@textString, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @textString), 1), '')
 select dbo.fn_ReplaceWithPattern(@textString,'%[0-9]%','',1)
```

output
[image]

if your data is stored in a table, and you need to update its value, you do so

```
update TableA
set ColumnX = dbo.fn_ReplaceWithPattern(ColumnX,'%[0-9]%','',1)
```

If you need it just in your select statment, you use this syntaxe

```
select dbo.fn_ReplaceWithPattern(ColumnX,'%[0-9]%','',1) as SanitizedValue
from TableA
```

Comment: Thanks Ismail, I am trying to implement it but having one issue...the text values with the phone numbers are stored in a column in a table, how would I re-write the values section? I tried this but it didn't work values (select column a from table 1) would I need to set @textString = (select column a from table 1) ?